# Minimize popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

How can I move my popup window back or minimize it?  The following code snippet doesn't work:

```
w = window.open('asdasd');
w.blur();
window.focus();
```

I need the same effect as in http://www.filesonic.com/file/2959312855/CoreczkaArena.rar, when you Click "SLOW DOWNLOAD" the popup with ad moves back under the main window.

Comment: Is it ethical to answer an evil question like this?

Comment: You apparently really like annoying your users. Popups are the spawn of satan.

Comment: How do You know for what I need this?

Answer (score 1):

Got You Then - Here The Solution

```
   var newWindow = window.open('Default.aspx');
   newWindow .opener.window.focus();
```

Comment: No :/ This only work when you allow moving window up/down in JavaScript options in firefox preferences. Method from my link works even if it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not do this.**

The reason for that is that your users' experience will suffer and that this type of behaviour is often considered harmful.

If you want to put some content "in the background", just **do it within current page by implementing CSS and JavaScript** scripts that make site behave as it would contain multiple "layers" or "windows". Try using [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/) for example.

If you insist on doing what you asked (creating new window and moving it in the back), someday it will probably stop working and your content will be blocked by popup blockers. But before that happens, you will probably receive negative feedback from the users of your site.

Comment: Ohhh thx for your info, maby my users needs it, U don't know what I have to do

Comment: @NagRock: You do not say, so I do not know. Thus I need to assume and in such case there is maybe 99% chance that you want to do something your users will not like and also high chance that their browsers will at least try to block it.

Answer (score -1):

There is not necessarily only bad intentions to want this type of behavior of the browser.
My web application is running on Chrome.
I need to launch http requests to call a web service in localhost for document management from the document server.
And I would like to avoid cluttering the user's desktop with extra windows.
With Window.open you can reduce to the size 100/100 but you can't minimize totally when launching the window.
On the other hand, manually, you can do it afterwards.
I don't see why it can't be done directly when the calling site is in https
Cpf

Comment: please consider web workers instead of new windows, or requesting in the same thread instead of opening a new window as it UX anti-pattern.